# How to extract specific content in a pandas dataframe with a regex?

Tags: python, regex, string, python-2.7, pandas

Consider the following pandas dataframe:

```
In [114]:

df['movie_title'].head()

​
Out[114]:

0     Toy Story (1995)
1     GoldenEye (1995)
2    Four Rooms (1995)
3    Get Shorty (1995)
4       Copycat (1995)
...
Name: movie_title, dtype: object
```

**Update:**
I would like to extract with a regular expression just the titles of the movies. So, let's use the following regex: `\b([^\d\W]+)\b`. So I tried the following:

```
df_3['movie_title'] = df_3['movie_title'].str.extract('\b([^\d\W]+)\b')
df_3['movie_title']
```

However, I get the following:

```
0       NaN
1       NaN
2       NaN
3       NaN
4       NaN
5       NaN
6       NaN
7       NaN
8       NaN
```

Any idea of how to extract specific features from text in a pandas dataframe?. More specifically, how can I extract just the titles of the movies in a completely new dataframe?. For instance, the desired output should be:

```
Out[114]:

0     Toy Story
1     GoldenEye
2    Four Rooms
3    Get Shorty
4       Copycat
...
Name: movie_title, dtype: object
```

Answer (score 60, accepted):

You can try [`str.extract`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.extract.html) and [`strip`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.strip.html), but better is use [`str.split`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.split.html), because in names of movies can be numbers too. Next solution is [`replace`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.replace.html) content of parentheses by `regex` and [`strip`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.strip.html)  leading and trailing whitespaces:

```
#convert column to string
df['movie_title'] = df['movie_title'].astype(str)

#but it remove numbers in names of movies too
df['titles'] = df['movie_title'].str.extract('([a-zA-Z ]+)', expand=False).str.strip()
df['titles1'] = df['movie_title'].str.split('(', 1).str[0].str.strip()
df['titles2'] = df['movie_title'].str.replace(r'\([^)]*\)', '').str.strip()
print df
          movie_title      titles      titles1      titles2
0  Toy Story 2 (1995)   Toy Story  Toy Story 2  Toy Story 2
1    GoldenEye (1995)   GoldenEye    GoldenEye    GoldenEye
2   Four Rooms (1995)  Four Rooms   Four Rooms   Four Rooms
3   Get Shorty (1995)  Get Shorty   Get Shorty   Get Shorty
4      Copycat (1995)     Copycat      Copycat      Copycat
```

Comment: I got this: `TypeError: extract() got an unexpected keyword argument 'expand'`

Comment: Do you update `pandas` to version `0.18.0`? Check it `print pd.show_versions()`

Comment: I updated and got this: `AttributeError: Can only use .str accessor with string values, which use np.object_ dtype in pandas`. Now I have: `byteorder: little
LC_ALL: None
LANG: None

pandas: 0.18.0
nose: 1.3.7
pip: 8.1.0`

Comment: Thanks for the help... just another issue, why when `astype(str)` is used I get the following exception: `UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\xe9' in position 3: ordinal not in range(128)`. Note that the econding of the file is `encoding='iso-8859-1`, I all ready set it in the pandas dataframe, however, I got the previous exception....how should I deal with this ecoding problem?

Comment: Yes:`df = pd.read_csv('ml-100k/u.item', \
                   sep = '|',names = ['movie_id','movie_title','release_date', \
                                      'video_release_date', 'IMDb-URL','unknown','Action','Adventure',\
                                      'Animation', 'Childrens','Comedy','Crime','Documentary'\
                                      ,'Drama','Fantasy','Film-Noir','Horror','Musical','Mystery',\
                                      'Romance','Sci-Fi','Thriller', 'War' ,'Western'],encoding='iso-8859-1')`

Comment: It seems very interesting, because I think string columns are converted to `utf-8` in `read_csv` by parameter `encoding`. Is posible share your file?

Comment: Yes I am just practicing with this [dataset](https://github.com/ryotat/mlss15/tree/master/python/datasets/ml-100k)... so what do you think it's happening?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/106551/discussion-between-jezrael-and-ml-student).

Comment: How would I, say, extract only movie title and titles1 using pandas?

Answer (score 10):

You should assign text group(s) with `()` like below to capture specific part of it.

```
new_df['just_movie_titles'] = df['movie_title'].str.extract('(.+?) \(')
new_df['just_movie_titles']
```

> **[pandas.core.strings.StringMethods.extract](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.15.2/generated/pandas.core.strings.StringMethods.extract.html)**
>
> **StringMethods.extract(pat, flags=0, **kwargs)**
>
> Find groups in each string using passed regular expression

Answer (score 1):

I wanted to extract the text after the symbol "@" and before the symbol "." (period) I tried this, it worked more or less because I have the symbol "@" but I don not want this symbol, anyway:

```
df['col'].astype(str).str.extract('(@.+.+)
```

Answer (score -1):

Using regular expressions to find a year stored between parentheses.
We specify the parantheses so we don't conflict with movies that have years in
their titles

```
movies_df['year'] = movies_df.title.str.extract('(\(\d\d\d\d\))',expand=False)
```

Removing the parentheses:

```
movies_df['year'] = movies_df.year.str.extract('(\d\d\d\d)',expand=False)
```

Removing the years from the 'title' column:

```
movies_df['title'] = movies_df.title.str.replace('(\(\d\d\d\d\))', '')
```

Applying the strip function to get rid of any ending whitespace characters that may have appeared:

```
movies_df['title'] = movies_df['title'].apply(lambda x: x.strip())
```